# ASP.NET CORE Kendo Grid: Populating a grid dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When a user clicks on a date using the Calendar it will populate the grid dynamically with the times. If someone enters data and there is no corresponding record the grid will insert a new record if the user edits an existing row that will fire an update. How do we implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The telerik components operate on a datasource behind the scenes.  I find the jquery datasource examples to be helpful for working with them [telerik jquery datasource](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/index)

when you configure your grid and add the save option it will call the sync method on the datasource.  the grid will track what types of changes you have made to the datasource ie insert,update,delete and will call the appropriate method for each change that you made.[datasource configuration and events](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource?wcmmode=disabled).  you just need to be sure you have a method in your controller to do what you want with each type of change.

if your grid is setup like below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Mymodel>()
                .Name("MyGrid")
                .Columns(col =>
                {
                    col.Bound(x => x.MyId).Hidden();
                    col.Bound(x => x.AnotherField).Title("Product Name");
                    col.Bound(x => x.Athirdfield);
                    col.Command(cmd => { cmd.Edit(); }).Title("Actions");
                })
                .ToolBar(tb => { tb.Save(); })
                .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Model(md =>
                {
                    md.Id(m => m.MyId);                        
                })
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "MyGrid"))
                .Create(cr => cr.Action("Create","MyGrid"))
                .Update(up => up.Action("Update", "MyGrid"))
                .Destroy(de => de.Action("Delete", "MyGrid")))
                .Filterable()
                .Pageable()
            )
```

Now when your grid sees that an insert (or creation) is necessary it will use the method and controller you identified in the .Create() method.

Then your controller just needs to handle the business logic of your operations like below (i only included a read and update method here)

```
public class MYGridController : Controller
{
    private readonly dbContext _context;
    public MyGridController(DB context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(await _context.MyModel.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request));
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, MyModel pm)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(pm);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(await new[] { pm }.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request, ModelState));
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
        }
        return Json(await new[] { pm }.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request, ModelState));

    }
}
```

I hope this helps.  I know how hard it can be to get the hang of these grids, but they are great once you understand how they work